# уведомление что браузер устарел

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

Как можно реализовать на *ASP.net*, чтобы выдавало уведомление, что браузер устарел?

Имеется сайт, написанный с помощью *HTML5* и он не работает в *Internet Explorer 8*. Нужно, чтобы пользователю, открывшему сайт, выдало уведомление, что его браузер устарел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте условный оператор

```
<!--[if условие]> HTML-код выводимый при выполнении условия <![endif]-->
```

в html коде страницы.

Выводим плашку с сообщением для IE8 и ниже:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<div class="warning">
    <span>
        Ваш браузер устарел. Обновите его.
    </span>
</div>
<![endif]-->
```

При таком методе браузер определяется на 100% правильно.

Линк http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii

Comment: Кстати да, хороший метод. Совсем про него забыл.

Comment: Помогло большое спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Советую js-плагин, типа https://github.com/TurnWheel/jReject,

либо https://github.com/nmsdvid/ie-alert

Answer (score -1):

А в чем, собственно, сложность? Создаете глобальный фильтр, проверяете в нем версию браузера - и делаете редирект для старых браузеров.

- [asp.net глобальный фильтр](https://www.google.ru/search?q=asp.net%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80)
- [asp.net проверка версии браузера](https://www.google.ru/search?q=asp.net%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)
- [asp.net фильтр редирект](https://www.google.ru/search?q=asp.net%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

Comment: А можно поподробней как это реализовать?

Comment: По каждой из частей - первая же ссылка в гугле ведет на достаточно подробное описание того, как это реализовать. А если вдруг первая непонятна - поможет вторая.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а если не поможет вторая - то возьмите третью?

Comment: @PashaPash, если совсем ничего не понятно - то можно и спросить. Но лично я не виду смысла пересказывать азы. Тем более что Visman предложил более красивое решение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тут половина вопросов - азы. но вроде как принято не посылать в гугл.

Comment: какая-то зашкаливающая концентрация Павлов в комментах