# Определение версии браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы если у пользователя браузера IE8 отображалась одна страница,а если другой браузер то другая страница?

Comment: можно попробовать `user-agent` проверить

Comment: @Grundy, мудришь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454633/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB/454645#454645

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.documentMode === 8) {
  // IE8 или его эмуляция
} else {
  // Что-то другое
}
```

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы данный скрипт грузился при загрузке страницы сразу после открытия?

Comment: @ChromeChrome, поместить его в `head`.